# Resolvent of a Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have a question about theory of Markov processes.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $E$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $\mathcal{B}(E)$ be its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ denotes a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$.   Let $X$ be a Markov process in a continuous time with value in the set $E$.

**We assume the following conditions holds**:

- $\mathcal{B}(E)=\sigma(C(E))$ where $C(E)$ denotes the set of all continuous ($\mathbb{R}$-valued) function on $E$
- For all $\omega \in \Omega$, $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is right continuous on $[0,\infty[$
- $P_{x}[X_{0}=x]=1\quad({}^{\forall} x\in E)$

In the above-mentioned setting, we define
\begin{align*}
R_{\alpha}f(x):=E_{x}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} f(X_{t})dt\right]\quad(\alpha>0,x \in E, f \in \mathcal{B}(E)^{+})
\end{align*}

**My question**:

Since $m$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists $\varphi \in \mathcal{B}(E)$ such that $\varphi(x)>0$ for all $x \in E$ . For this $\varphi$, $R_{1}\varphi(x)>0,\,x \in E$ is hold?

**My attempt**:

**Case1: $\varphi$ is continuous**

Since $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is right continuous and $P_{x}[X_{0}=x]=1\quad({}^{\forall} x\in E)$, it is obvious that  $R_{1}\varphi(x)>0$ forall $x \in E$ .

**Case2 $\varphi$ is not continuous**

Although I think $\varphi$ is a kind of continuous function by the condition $\mathcal{B}(E)=\sigma(C(E))$, I don't know how to the proper way to use this condition.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is used to represent both a $\sigma-$algebra  of subsets and a collection of functions on the probability space. Probably a simple typo. Should it be $C(E)$ is a few places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $R_1 \varphi>0$  holds true.

Suppose that $R_1 \varphi(x)=0$ for some $x \in E$. Then

$$\mathbb{E}^x \left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{- t} \varphi(X_t) \, dt \right)=0$$

implies

$$e^{- t} \varphi (X_t)=0$$

almost everywhere (since the mapping $(\omega,t) \mapsto e^{- t} \varphi(X_t(\omega))$ is non-negative). Hence,

$$\varphi(X_t)=0$$

almost everywhere. This is a contradiction to our assumption that $\varphi>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to understand.